# strange behaviour with viewport meta set to device-width and initial-scale

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools, media-queries

This is a test page mentioned in [Google web dev responsive design article](https://web.dev/responsive-web-design-basics/) for testing the viewport meta tag:

https://with-vp-meta.glitch.me/

There is a strange behavior observed when testing with chrome dev tools responsive devices in devices with very low width (at least below 320px)

If you keep on reducing the width, there comes a point where the html body width is not equal to the device pixel width anymore (though it should be equal as per the width=device-width value).

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the body tag is selected in the Elements panel. The size of the selection is much less than the 81px device width as mentioned in the dev tools device header (81 x 711)

If you look at the dimensions in computed styles: the dimensions are mentioned as 81px width

This is a real issue, actually happening with my website (on not so smaller width), and this is just an example to recreate it easily.

I suspect this has something to do with the viewport meta tag and it's handling, but i am not able to pinpoint what the problem is. I have tried different combinations of width and initial-scale to recreate this scenario in other dimensions, but wasn't able to recreate a scenario where the rendered body width is less than the viewport width, but devtools inspect still shows the dimensions as correct, although the rendered dimensions do not match the pixel dimensions?

Comment: It's more likely a fixed width element which is overflowing the body

Comment: Looks like the actual text itself isn't wrapping, try `hyphens: auto` and see what happens

Comment: you are actually right, this helped me understand the issue better and it seems there are some elements on my website which overflow the body and hence the device width works correctly, but the body width is constrained by the overflowing elements.

Comment: In this case, the problem gets solved by setting word-break: break-word ,( hyphens:auto did not work though)